# $_POST empty in post Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I tried to check the solution in the other similar post on the forum, but I did not resolve my problem yet.
So, I have this Ajax Request in my .js page

JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.mySubmitTextButton', function() {
    var dataToSend = {};
    dataToSend.text = $("#comment").val();
    console.log(dataToSend);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../submitPages/submitText.php",
        data: dataToSend,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            var mediaToClone = $(".rowToCopy").clone();
            $(".userId", mediaToClone).html(result.user);
            $(".textTweet", mediaToClone).html(result.text);
            $(".userAvatar", mediaToClone).attr("src",result.avatar);
            mediaToClone.removeClass("rowToCopy hidden");
            mediaToClone.appendTo($(".tweetBox"));
        },
        error: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
});
```

PHP Code

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
include ("../db/db.php");

var_dump($_POST);
if(submitText($_POST["text"], $_SESSION["name"])){  //which is the call to the query function
    $propic = getUserPic($_SESSION["name"]);
    $result = array(
        "text" => $_POST["text"],
        "user" => $_SESSION["username"],
        "avatar"=>$propic
    );
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

FROM THE BROWSER

```
   Form Data
     text: test  //This is the Params Tab


    //In the response tab
    <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
    'text' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'ccccccccc'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
</pre>{"text":"ccccccccc","user":"blackout_chisel","avatar":"..\/..\/img\/useravatar\/0826fc411cd2dc627ddd0b0cac0f7fb7.jpg"}
```

The datas seem to be correctly passed from the js to php (in the browser console I see the parameters correctly passed), but with var_dump($_POST) in the php file, I get an empty array, so I can't use $_POST["text"] in the query case the index is undefined.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the data as seen in the console. It seems to me you're not sending a field name along with data, but just a piece of data.

You're certainly not serializing the data on a form.

Comment: @Difster jQuery automatically serializes it if `data:` is an object.

Comment: @romph That's equivalent to what he wrote.

Comment: Is `.mySubmitButton` a `type="submit"` button? Use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the normal form submission.

Comment: Check if you're not accidentally changing post in `"../db/db.php"`

Comment: Add a success and error handlers and `console.log` results. What do you have? Also try to add a `console.log(dataToSend);` after `dataToSend.text = $("#comment").val();`. What is printed in console?

Comment: direct try to send data :- `$(document).on('click', '.mySubmitTextButton', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../submitPages/submitText.php",
        data: {'text':$("#comment").val()},
        dataType: "json"
    });
});`

Comment: I edited the original post with what you ask. @anwerj I'm not changing anything; Barmar, it is just a button.

Comment: @AlivetoDie, I tried, same result

Comment: Can also look in Network tab of console. When you click submit, a new entry will appear. Click that and view what you sent, and what the response was.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thanks all, I had a misunderstood on it. It works perfectly. I was trying to see the result var_dump($_POST), when the ajax call was already done. That's why it was obviously empty.